# MS Teams and Graph API : Cannot activate class team with registered AAD application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've an Azure Application registered with some API permissions.
With Graph API and a valid token for this application, I can easily create teams, add owners, members, etc.

Still with Graph API, I need to activate class teams (a class team is not activated by default to allow the teacher to prepare content before opening it to students).

Manually activating a class team directly from Teams UI is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com).
It works fine.

Programmatically activating a class team with Graph API is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com).
It consists of using the PATCH method on the team with the following JSON body :

```json
{
  "isMembershipLimitedToOwners": false
}
```

It works fine when sending request with an administrative AAD account : `isMembershipLimitedToOwners` attribute is updated and students are automatically added to the team.

However, it doesn't work when calling API with AAD application token : `isMembershipLimitedToOwners` attribute is correctly updated too but students are not actually added to the team and on Teams UI, a warning is shown :
[Teams screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs6OO.png)
If I click on "Retry", students are added to team...

It seems that (asynchronous ?) background operations are not correctly executed.

I tried to add some rôles to registered application but with no success.

Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, this is a bug in the MS Graph API. A ticket is being processed [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/20912).